# Why times by delta time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time, timedelta

I'm making a game using unity and making some objects rotate in place. Ive looked around on how to get this accomplished and found out how. --->

```
 public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour {

 int speed = 2;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(15, 30, 45) * Time.deltaTime *speed);

  }
}
```

Now my question is, Why do I have to do  "  * Time.deltaTime  "? Please explain this whole line.

Thank you,
Rom

Comment: [Unity-Delta Time](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/delta-time).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand why you must use Time.deltaTime, first you need to understand the high level flow of a game engine.

Basically, a game is an application which needs to constantly wait for input from the player and react to that input and render the scene. At the core of every game there's a game loop, which is active as long as the application is running. That can be as simple as this:

```
while(active) 
{
  update(); // react to player's input/update player position etc
  render(); // render the scene
}
```

As you see the code inside the loop is constantly being executed until the player's actions result in the loop termination (maybe he clicked on 'Quit' from the game menu). In Unity, Updates of all your scripts attached to all your game objects are being invoked in the game loop.

Depending on the machine the application is running on, there can be varying number update passes during a given time frame, e.g. you can have varying frame rates based on the machine configuration. This will really mess things up if you don't have a way to synchronize all your updates somehow to the real physical time.

To do that, you use **Time.DeltaTime** in Unity Script. This is simply a parameter which tells you how much time has passed since the last time your script's Update was invoked.

To answer specifically your question, multiplying your rotation update with the deltaTime is a way of making sure the rotation speed of your object is the same regardless of the framerate.

Comment: Interesting. I read that FixedUpdate would help in keeping the functionality of physics in a game running without the need to worry about the framerate.

Comment: @Rom, you're right. FixedUpdate is recommended to use for physics updates. While Update is invoked before each frame render, FixedUpdate gets called less frequently. Physics doesn't need to be so accurate for the game to be perfectly playable. So updating physics-related logic can go to FixedUpdate. Things like rendering the scene and getting user input, on the other hand, are more critical hence you will be better of processing those in the standard Update function.

Comment: Couldn't I just do this?
public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour {
     int speed = 2;
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void FixedUpdate () {
        
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(15, 30, 45)  *speed);
 
 }
}

Comment: @Rom The frequency of FixedUpdate calls is controlled via the Time Manager in your project settings (go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Time). There you can configure Fixed Timestep variable to achieve whatever you want. But I still don't think that animating in FixedUpdate is a good idea. If you reduce the frequency of FixedUpdate calls, your animation will look jagged.

Answer (score 1):

A time delta is typically the time difference between each game loop update or draw cycle. It allows game loop / draw cycle events happen independent of CPU speed (animations and events won't speed up or slow down depending on system resources / CPU speed).

Those of us old enough can remember a time when games did not do this. Some games would run quite a bit quicker with higher frequency CPUs. Oregon Trail is a prime example.

Answer (score 0):

Framerate independent games are games that run at the same speed, no matter the framerate. For example, a game might run at 30 FPS (Frames Per Second) on a slow computer, and 60 FPS on a fast one. A framerate independent game progresses at the same speed on both computers (objects appear to move at the same speed). On the other hand, a framerate dependent game progresses at half the speed on the slow computer, in a sort of slow-motion effect. Making framerate independent games is important to make sure your game is enjoyable and playable for everyone, no matter what kind of computer they have. Games which slow down when the framerate dips can severely affect gameplay, making players get frustrated and quit!
So this Time.deltaTime makes the movement framerate indipendent.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, in order for the `transform` to rotate at the desired `speed`, it must rotate a small amount each frame. Putting all those little rotations together make the full rotation you're looking for, at the `speed` you desire.

`Time.deltaTime` is the time since the last frame (i.e. the time since `Update()` was previously called).

Answer (score 0):

Time.deltaTime is used to make the action independent of frame rate. The line of code works similarly on all devices regardless of fps. Therefore,here, your object will rotate the similar amount of degrees in all devices in a fixed amount of time.

for transform.Rotate(new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime *speed);
Lets say the fps is 60(60 frames in 1 second). Time for each frame is 0.016666666. The rotation of the object in 1 second is 2 unit(0.0166666*60 frames *2(where 2 is speed)

If the fps is 30, i.e. 30 frames in one second, time for each frame is 0.03333. The rotation of the object in 1 second is 2 unit(0.033333*30 frames *2(where 2 is speed)

For better understanding, go through the following link:
http://codesaying.com/time-deltatime-in-unity3d/

Answer (score 0):

`Time.DeltaTime` is a way of making sure the `speed/move/rotation` of your object is the same regardless of the framerate.

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    const int moveSpeed = 1;
    public float currentX = 0;

    void Update()
    {
        var moveSize = Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
        currentX += moveSize;
    }
}
```

*If we write out the actual values (we are setting `Time.deltaTime` to a constant for simplicity):*

[image: Example1]

[image: Example2]

[image: Example3]

**Summary:**

1. For smaller values of `Time.deltaTime` there are more frames but smaller movements (moveSize)
2. For bigger values of `Time.deltaTime` there are less frames but bigger movements (moveSize)

They still both get to the same `currentX` value regardless of time. This works for bigger and smaller values of `Time.deltaTime`.